# Combining Two lists without Itertools

Tags: python, python-3.x

For part of a project, I have to show all possible combinations of three-colorings for a given graph, defined in a dictionary. This does not check for valid colorings, as it is simply a helper method.

**Example**

```
three_color({"A":["B"], "B":["A"]})

 Should give us:

 [{'A': '1', 'B': '1'},
 {'A': '1', 'B': '2'},
 {'A': '1', 'B': '3'},
 {'A': '2', 'B': '1'},
 {'A': '2', 'B': '2'},
 {'A': '2', 'B': '3'},
 {'A': '3', 'B': '1'},
 {'A': '3', 'B': '2'},
 {'A': '3', 'B': '3'}]
```

However, we are prohibited from importing any libraries. Currently, I am working with this solution and trying to transfer it without using product()

```
coloring = ([dict(zip(graph, p)) for p in product(colors,repeat = len(graph))])
```

My current solution is based on the fact, according to the documentation, `product(A, B)` returns the same as `((x,y) for x in A for y in B).`

Currently, I have

```
def three_color(graph):
    colors = ['1','2','3']

    coloring = ([dict(zip(graph, p)) for p in ((x,y) for x in colors for y in (range(1,4)))])
    #coloring = ([dict(zip(graph, p)) for p in product(colors,repeat = len(graph))])

    return coloring
```

This gives me the correct answer when using graph `{"A":["B"], "B":["A"]}`, but it doesn't seem to work when with any other number of vertices.

**Example 2**

```
three_color({"A":["B","C"], "B":["A"], "C":["A"]})

Should give us:
[{'A': '1', 'B': '1', 'C': '1'},
 {'A': '1', 'B': '1', 'C': '2'},
 {'A': '1', 'B': '1', 'C': '3'},
 {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '1'},
 {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '2'},
 {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'},
 {'A': '1', 'B': '3', 'C': '1'},
 {'A': '1', 'B': '3', 'C': '2'},
 {'A': '1', 'B': '3', 'C': '3'},
 {'A': '2', 'B': '1', 'C': '1'},
 {'A': '2', 'B': '1', 'C': '2'},
 {'A': '2', 'B': '1', 'C': '3'},
 {'A': '2', 'B': '2', 'C': '1'},
 {'A': '2', 'B': '2', 'C': '2'},
 {'A': '2', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'},
 {'A': '2', 'B': '3', 'C': '1'},
 {'A': '2', 'B': '3', 'C': '2'},
 {'A': '2', 'B': '3', 'C': '3'},
 {'A': '3', 'B': '1', 'C': '1'},
 {'A': '3', 'B': '1', 'C': '2'},
 {'A': '3', 'B': '1', 'C': '3'},
 {'A': '3', 'B': '2', 'C': '1'},
 {'A': '3', 'B': '2', 'C': '2'},
 {'A': '3', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'},
 {'A': '3', 'B': '3', 'C': '1'},
 {'A': '3', 'B': '3', 'C': '2'},
 {'A': '3', 'B': '3', 'C': '3'}]

But it gives me:
[{'A': '1', 'B': 1},
 {'A': '1', 'B': 2},
 {'A': '1', 'B': 3},
 {'A': '2', 'B': 1},
 {'A': '2', 'B': 2},
 {'A': '2', 'B': 3},
 {'A': '3', 'B': 1},
 {'A': '3', 'B': 2},
 {'A': '3', 'B': 3}]
```

Any guidance or assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: For starters, when you have three arguments, `product()` behaves differently than it does with two arguments. Don't bang your head against the wall making this a one-liner; split it out into your own `product()` function.

Answer (score 2):

If you check out the [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), they provide implementations of most of their builtin functions.

For [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), the only difference in the one they provide is that the `itertools` implementation does not build up intermediate results in memory.

You can take the function provided in the documentation, and use it as your product function in your example:

```
def product(*args, repeat=1):
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)

def coloring(graph):
  colors = ['1','2','3']
  return [dict(zip(graph, p)) for p in product(colors,repeat = len(graph))]

print(coloring({"A":["B","C"], "B":["A"], "C":["A"]}))
```

Output:

```
[{'A': '1', 'B': '1', 'C': '1'}, {'A': '1', 'B': '1', 'C': '2'}, {'A': '1', 'B': '1', 'C': '3'}, {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '1'}, {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '2'}, {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'}, {'A': '1', 'B': '3', 'C': '1'}, {'A': '1', 'B': '3', 'C': '2'}, {'A': '1', 'B': '3', 'C': '3'}, {'A': '2', 'B': '1', 'C': '1'}, {'A': '2', 'B': '1', 'C': '2'}, {'A': '2', 'B': '1', 'C': '3'}, {'A': '2', 'B': '2', 'C': '1'}, {'A': '2', 'B': '2', 'C': '2'}, {'A': '2', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'}, {'A': '2', 'B': '3', 'C': '1'}, {'A': '2', 'B': '3', 'C': '2'}, {'A': '2', 'B': '3', 'C': '3'}, {'A': '3', 'B': '1', 'C': '1'}, {'A': '3', 'B': '1', 'C': '2'}, {'A': '3', 'B': '1', 'C': '3'}, {'A': '3', 'B': '2', 'C': '1'}, {'A': '3', 'B': '2', 'C': '2'}, {'A': '3', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'}, {'A': '3', 'B': '3', 'C': '1'}, {'A': '3', 'B': '3', 'C': '2'}, {'A': '3', 'B': '3', 'C': '3'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple recursion with a generator function, then use `zip` to pair the full colorings to the graph:

```
def full_product(d, d1, current = []):
   if d == len(current):
      yield current
   else:
      for i in range(d):
        for b in range(1, d1):
           yield from full_product(d, d1, current + [b])

def final_results(data):
  def wrapper():
    for colors in data():
       full_set = set(reduce(lambda x, y:x+y, [[a]+b for a, b in colors.items()]))
       result = list(full_product(len(full_set), 4))
       last_result = [a for i, a in enumerate(result) if all(a != c for c in result[:i])]
       yield [dict(zip(full_set, i)) for i in last_result]
  return wrapper

@final_results
def full_results():
   return [{"A":["B"], "B":["A"]}, {"A":["B","C"], "B":["A"], "C":["A"]}]

print(list(full_results()))
```

Output:

```
[[{'A': 1, 'B': 1}, {'A': 1, 'B': 2}, {'A': 1, 'B': 3}, {'A': 2, 'B': 1}, {'A': 2, 'B': 2}, {'A': 2, 'B': 3}, {'A': 3, 'B': 1}, {'A': 3, 'B': 2}, {'A': 3, 'B': 3}], [{'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1}, {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 2}, {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 3}, {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 1}, {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 2}, {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}, {'A': 1, 'B': 3, 'C': 1}, {'A': 1, 'B': 3, 'C': 2}, {'A': 1, 'B': 3, 'C': 3}, {'A': 2, 'B': 1, 'C': 1}, {'A': 2, 'B': 1, 'C': 2}, {'A': 2, 'B': 1, 'C': 3}, {'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 1}, {'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 2}, {'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}, {'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 1}, {'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 2}, {'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 3}, {'A': 3, 'B': 1, 'C': 1}, {'A': 3, 'B': 1, 'C': 2}, {'A': 3, 'B': 1, 'C': 3}, {'A': 3, 'B': 2, 'C': 1}, {'A': 3, 'B': 2, 'C': 2}, {'A': 3, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}, {'A': 3, 'B': 3, 'C': 1}, {'A': 3, 'B': 3, 'C': 2}, {'A': 3, 'B': 3, 'C': 3}]]
```